# How to return value of unbound column in combo box

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

How can I get the value of an unbound column of a combo box using the expression builder in Access 2007?

I have a form that controls a query through a combo box where I select a month on the form and Access runs a query for items pertaining to that month. Then I have a report that based on that query.

I'd like the report header to display the month that was selected. I made a text box in the report that uses an expression as the control source like so "=[Forms]![frm Annual Notices Report]![Combo10]". Which works expect it returns the value in Col1. How can I make my text box display the month in Col2? I've tried "=[Forms]![frmMyform]![Combo10(1)]", but it returns an error.

My combo box is setup like this:

```
Col1       Col2
1          January
2          February
3          March
4          April
...        ...
```

I need to use the month index to control the query, but I also want to make a text box in a report show the month as written.

TL;DR:
How can I make a text box display the month in Col2?

Currently I have this: "=[Forms]![frmMyForm]![Combo10]"

I think I need something like this: "=[Forms]![frmMyform]![Combo10(1)]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `.Column` property.

```
=[Forms]![frmMyForm]![Combo10].Column(1)
```

is the second column.

BTW, there is also the `MonthName()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know about the MonthName() function, but I will look into it. Still very much a beginner at this stuff.